# (Openwrt) How to set a service to automatically restart at a particular time in Luci Web interface Schedule tasks?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, openwrt, crontab

I am having problems with my Openwrt router when rebooting, I cannot connect to the Internet unless i restart the firewall service in Luci.

I need help with a command that can restart the firewall service everyday after a reboot at 5:55am.

Thank you.

Comment: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/cron

Answer (score 3):

In the LEDE GUI, go to Schedule Tasks and then enter the following code (change the number for what time you want it to restart)

```
# Reboot at 4am every day
0 4 * * * reboot
```